# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' Map toList error problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to toList the json data coming from the API service and list it on FutureBuilder. But no matter what I do, it returns catch. What could be the problem? Json value is coming but I can't use toList property. What should I do about it?

Payment Service :

```dart
Future<List<PaymentData>> paymentGetList() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  dynamic responseData;
  String token = await getToken();
  final paymentListApiUrl = Uri.parse(
      apiUrlKey + preferences.getString('apiUrl').toString() + paymentListUrl);

try {

  final response = await http.post(paymentListApiUrl, headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }, body: {
      'filters': '',
      'params': '',
      'limit': '10',
      'offset': '0',
      'sorting': ''
    });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var jsonArray = jsonData['data'];
    List<PaymentData> jsonResult =
        (jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List)
            .map((e) => PaymentData.fromMap(e))
            .toList();
    responseData = jsonArray;
  }

} catch (e) {

  print("Error:  $e");

}

  return responseData;
}
```

result print : flutter: Error:  type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

PaymentModel

```dart
PaymentData paymentDataFromMap(String str) =>
    PaymentData.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String paymentDataToMap(PaymentData data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class PaymentData {
    PaymentData({
        required this.id,
        required this.paymentsendId,
        required this.collectionEmail,
        required this.collectionSms,
        required this.periodOrder,
        required this.email,
        required this.cardType1,
        required this.cardType2,
        required this.cardNameSurname,
        required this.comment,
        required this.datumNull,
        required this.customerId,
        required this.orderid,
        required this.installmentNumber,
        required this.plusInstallment,
        required this.status,
        required this.maskedCard,
        required this.totalWithCommison,
        required this.totalWithoutCommison,
        required this.currencyType,
        required this.transactionData,
        required this.transactionBank,
        required this.transactionType,
        required this.partial,
        required this.nameSurname,
        required this.phoneNumber,
        required this.postCode,
        required this.city,
        required this.district,
        required this.country,
        required this.paymentType,
        required this.memberCode,
        required this.paymentNote,
        required this.paymentAddress,
        required this.erpOrderIds,
        required this.erpStatus,
        required this.erpStatusMsg,
        required this.idNumber,
        required this.taxNumber,
        required this.paymentIp,
        required this.space1,
        required this.space2,
        required this.space3,
        required this.space4,
        required this.space5,
        required this.space6,
        required this.space7,
        required this.posId,
        required this.createdIn,
        required this.updatedIn,
    });

    final String id;
    final String paymentsendId;
    final String collectionEmail;
    final String collectionSms;
    final String periodOrder;
    final String email;
    final String cardType1;
    final String cardType2;
    final String cardNameSurname;
    final String comment;
    final String datumNull;
    final String customerId;
    final String orderid;
    final String installmentNumber;
    final String plusInstallment;
    final String status;
    final String maskedCard;
    final String totalWithCommison;
    final String totalWithoutCommison;
    final String currencyType;
    final String transactionData;
    final String transactionBank;
    final String transactionType;
    final String partial;
    final String nameSurname;
    final String phoneNumber;
    final String postCode;
    final String city;
    final String district;
    final String country;
    final String paymentType;
    final String memberCode;
    final String paymentNote;
    final String paymentAddress;
    final String erpOrderIds;
    final String erpStatus;
    final String erpStatusMsg;
    final String idNumber;
    final String taxNumber;
    final String paymentIp;
    final String space1;
    final String space2;
    final String space3;
    final String space4;
    final String space5;
    final String space6;
    final String space7;
    final String posId;
    final DateTime createdIn;
    final DateTime updatedIn;

    factory PaymentData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PaymentData(
        id: json["id"],
        paymentsendId: json["paymentsend_id"],
        collectionEmail: json["collection_email"],
        collectionSms: json["collection_sms"],
        periodOrder: json["period_order"],
        email: json["email"],
        cardType1: json["card_type1"],
        cardType2: json["card_type2"],
        cardNameSurname: json["card_name_surname"],
        comment: json["comment"],
        datumNull: json["NULL"],
        customerId: json["customer_id"],
        orderid: json["orderid"],
        installmentNumber: json["installment_number"],
        plusInstallment: json["plus_installment"],
        status: json["status"],
        maskedCard: json["masked_card"],
        totalWithCommison: json["total_with_commison"],
        totalWithoutCommison: json["total_without_commison"],
        currencyType: json["currency_type"],
        transactionData: json["transaction_data"],
        transactionBank: json["transaction_bank"],
        transactionType: json["transaction_type"],
        partial: json["partial"],
        nameSurname: json["name_surname"],
        phoneNumber: json["phone_number"],
        postCode: json["post_code"],
        city: json["city"],
        district: json["district"],
        country: json["country"],
        paymentType: json["payment_type"],
        memberCode: json["member_code"],
        paymentNote: json["payment_note"],
        paymentAddress: json["payment_address"],
        erpOrderIds: json["erp_order_ids"],
        erpStatus: json["erp_status"],
        erpStatusMsg: json["erp_status_msg"],
        idNumber: json["id_number"],
        taxNumber: json["tax_number"],
        paymentIp: json["payment_ip"],
        space1: json["space1"],
        space2: json["space2"],
        space3: json["space3"],
        space4: json["space4"],
        space5: json["space5"],
        space6: json["space6"],
        space7: json["space7"],
        posId: json["pos_id"],
        createdIn: DateTime.parse(json["created_in"]),
        updatedIn: DateTime.parse(json["updated_in"]),
    );

    factory PaymentData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PaymentData(
        id: json["id"],
        paymentsendId: json["paymentsend_id"],
        collectionEmail: json["collection_email"],
        collectionSms: json["collection_sms"],
        periodOrder: json["period_order"],
        email: json["email"],
        cardType1: json["card_type1"],
        cardType2: json["card_type2"],
        cardNameSurname: json["card_name_surname"],
        comment: json["comment"],
        datumNull: json["NULL"],
        customerId: json["customer_id"],
        orderid: json["orderid"],
        installmentNumber: json["installment_number"],
        plusInstallment: json["plus_installment"],
        status: json["status"],
        maskedCard: json["masked_card"],
        totalWithCommison: json["total_with_commison"],
        totalWithoutCommison: json["total_without_commison"],
        currencyType: json["currency_type"],
        transactionData: json["transaction_data"],
        transactionBank: json["transaction_bank"],
        transactionType: json["transaction_type"],
        partial: json["partial"],
        nameSurname: json["name_surname"],
        phoneNumber: json["phone_number"],
        postCode: json["post_code"],
        city: json["city"],
        district: json["district"],
        country: json["country"],
        paymentType: json["payment_type"],
        memberCode: json["member_code"],
        paymentNote: json["payment_note"],
        paymentAddress: json["payment_address"],
        erpOrderIds: json["erp_order_ids"],
        erpStatus: json["erp_status"],
        erpStatusMsg: json["erp_status_msg"],
        idNumber: json["id_number"],
        taxNumber: json["tax_number"],
        paymentIp: json["payment_ip"],
        space1: json["space1"],
        space2: json["space2"],
        space3: json["space3"],
        space4: json["space4"],
        space5: json["space5"],
        space6: json["space6"],
        space7: json["space7"],
        posId: json["pos_id"],
        createdIn: DateTime.parse(json["created_in"]),
        updatedIn: DateTime.parse(json["updated_in"]));
  }

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "paymentsend_id": paymentsendId,
        "collection_email": collectionEmail,
        "collection_sms": collectionSms,
        "period_order": periodOrder,
        "email": email,
        "card_type1": cardType1,
        "card_type2": cardType2,
        "card_name_surname": cardNameSurname,
        "comment": comment,
        "NULL": datumNull,
        "customer_id": customerId,
        "orderid": orderid,
        "installment_number": installmentNumber,
        "plus_installment": plusInstallment,
        "status": status,
        "masked_card": maskedCard,
        "total_with_commison": totalWithCommison,
        "total_without_commison": totalWithoutCommison,
        "currency_type": currencyType,
        "transaction_data": transactionData,
        "transaction_bank": transactionBank,
        "transaction_type": transactionType,
        "partial": partial,
        "name_surname": nameSurname,
        "phone_number": phoneNumber,
        "post_code": postCode,
        "city": city,
        "district": district,
        "country": country,
        "payment_type": paymentType,
        "member_code": memberCode,
        "payment_note": paymentNote,
        "payment_address": paymentAddress,
        "erp_order_ids": erpOrderIds,
        "erp_status": erpStatus,
        "erp_status_msg": erpStatusMsg,
        "id_number": idNumber,
        "tax_number": taxNumber,
        "payment_ip": paymentIp,
        "space1": space1,
        "space2": space2,
        "space3": space3,
        "space4": space4,
        "space5": space5,
        "space6": space6,
        "space7": space7,
        "pos_id": posId,
        "created_in": createdIn.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_in": updatedIn.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

When I print on Payment_model.dart, I get the following result.

```
[{id: 1, paymentsend_id: , collection_email: 0, collection_sms: 0, period_order: 0, email: mail@site.com, card_type1: cardfinans, card_type2: troy, card_name_surname: asktest, comment: , NULL: , customer_id: 123, orderid: 123123321, installment_number: 3, plus_installment: , status: 3D-POST, masked_card: 111111** **** 1111, total_with_commison: 1000.0000, total_without_commison: 1000.0000, currency_type: null, transaction_data: , transaction_bank: ing, transaction_type: 2, partial: , name_surname: asktest, phone_number: 1233123123, post_code: , city: Gaziantep, district: sahinbey, country: TR, payment_type: 3d, member_code: , payment_note: , payment_address: , erp_order_ids: , erp_status: , erp_status_msg: , id_number: , tax_number: , payment_ip: 111.111.11.11, space1: 12/2024, space2: , space3: , space4: log, space5: null, space6: null, space7: null, pos_id: null, created_in: 2021-11-26 12:54:07, updated_in: 0000-00-00 00:00:00}..]
```

Comment: Are you sure all the fields in your JSON have values and are not `null`? I can e.g. see in your printed list that a lot of the fields are `null` but your `PaymentData` does not allow any of the fields to be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has some NULL values. So it's not a good idea to make all your fields nonnullable. If you're sure about 'this field of the JSON will never have null value' then make it non-nullable. Otherwise, change them like this:

```
final String? comment;
...
```

remove `required`

```
this.comment
...
```

Comment: The last step is not necessary since it does not prevent us from having `null` values. It just forces us to provide a value for this named argument. But if the type are nullable, we can just provide `null`.

Answer (score -1):

You could change the `fromMap` function in `PaymentModel.dart` file like this to avoid access key with no value

```
factory PaymentData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PaymentData(
    id: json["id"] == null ? "" : json["id"],
    paymentsendId: json["paymentsend_id"] == null ? "" : json["paymentsend_id"],
    collectionEmail: json["collection_email"] == null ? "" : json["collection_email"],
    collectionSms: json["collection_sms"] == null ? "" : json["collection_sms"],
    periodOrder: json["period_order"] == null ? "" : json["period_order"],
    email: json["email"] == null ? "" : json["email"],
    cardType1: json["card_type1"] == null ? "" : json["card_type1"],
    cardType2: json["card_type2"] == null ? "" : json["card_type2"],
    cardNameSurname: json["card_name_surname"] == null ? "" : json["card_name_surname"],
    comment: json["comment"] == null ? "" : json["comment"],
    datumNull: json["NULL"] == null ? "" : json["NULL"],
    customerId: json["customer_id"] == null ? "" : json["customer_id"],
    orderid: json["orderid"] == null ? "" json["orderid"]: ,
    installmentNumber: json["installment_number"] == null ? "" : json["installment_number"],
    plusInstallment: json["plus_installment"] == null ? "" : json["plus_installment"],
    status: json["status"] == null ? "" : json["status"],
    maskedCard: json["masked_card"] == null ? "" : json["masked_card"],
    totalWithCommison: json["total_with_commison"] == null ? "" : json["total_with_commison"],
    totalWithoutCommison: json["total_without_commison"] == null ? "" : json["total_without_commison"],
    currencyType: json["currency_type"] == null ? "" : json["currency_type"],
    transactionData: json["transaction_data"] == null ? "" : json["transaction_data"],
    transactionBank: json["transaction_bank"] == null ? "" : json["transaction_bank"],
    transactionType: json["transaction_type"] == null ? "" : json["transaction_type"],
    partial: json["partial"] == null ? "" : json["partial"],
    nameSurname: json["name_surname"] == null ? "" : json["name_surname"],
    phoneNumber: json["phone_number"] == null ? "" : json["phone_number"],
    postCode: json["post_code"] == null ? "" : json["post_code"],
    city: json["city"] == null ? "" : json["city"],
    district: json["district"] == null ? "" : json["district"],
    country: json["country"] == null ? "" : json["country"],
    paymentType: json["payment_type"] == null ? "" : json["payment_type"],
    memberCode: json["member_code"] == null ? "" : json["member_code"],
    paymentNote: json["payment_note"] == null ? "" : json["payment_note"],
    paymentAddress: json["payment_address"] == null ? "" : json["payment_address"],
    erpOrderIds: json["erp_order_ids"] == null ? "" : json["erp_order_ids"],
    erpStatus: json["erp_status"] == null ? "" : json["erp_status"],
    erpStatusMsg: json["erp_status_msg"] == null ? "" : json["erp_status_msg"],
    idNumber: json["id_number"] == null ? "" : json["id_number"],
    taxNumber: json["tax_number"] == null ? "" : json["tax_number"],
    paymentIp: json["payment_ip"] == null ? "" : json["payment_ip"],
    space1: json["space1"] == null ? "" : json["space1"],
    space2: json["space2"] == null ? "" : json["space2"],
    space3: json["space3"] == null ? "" : json["space3"],
    space4: json["space4"] == null ? "" : json["space4"],
    space5: json["space5"] == null ? "" : json["space5"],
    space6: json["space6"] == null ? "" : json["space6"],
    space7: json["space7"] == null ? "" : json["space7"],
    posId: json["pos_id"] == null ? "" : json["pos_id"],
    createdIn: DateTime.parse(json["created_in"]),
    updatedIn: DateTime.parse(json["updated_in"]),
);
```

And do the same with `fromJson` function

Comment: This is an absolute terrible way to handle `null` values in data. You should use nullable types instead of converting your null-values into empty Strings since you would otherwise not be able to tell apart cases where a field are empty or not set. Also, you would end up printing a lot of empty values around your code and need to check if length are 0 to determine if the field are not set. Instead, you could have used `null` and let the type system help you ensure you are handling values that potentially can be null.

Comment: Instead of this, you should identify what fields can potentially be null, and use nullable types for these fields. Then, you can later in your program determine what should be done in case a given value are `null`.

Comment: you can just write `json["id"] ?? ""` instead of `json["id"] == null ? "" : json["id"]`